# Assign a Shell variable in AWK

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk

I have strings like this

```
/home/rm/home-scripts/originals/audicerttest/incoming/TEST040511.txt
/home/rm/home-scripts/originals/audicerttest2/incoming/TEST040512.txt
/home/rm/home-scripts/originals/audicerttest3/incoming/TEST040513.txt
```

etc..I want to extract strings 'audicerttest/incoming', audicerttest2/incoming' etc into a shell variable and use it later in the script. I tried something like this.

```
for file in `find ${ROOT}/* -type f | grep -v -f test.txt`
do
let count++
echo ${count}: ${file}
echo ${file} | eval $(awk '{split($0,a,"/"); print "abc=a[6]/a[7]"}' < /dev/null)
echo abc====$abc
done
```

but its not giving any output for abc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of issues, but let's isolate problems and tackle them one at a time.

**Given** - Raw string:

```
/home/rm/home-scripts/originals/audicerttest/incoming/TEST040511.txt
```

**Desired Output** - You want this part to be saved in a variable:

```
audicerttest/incoming
```

**How-To** - This will do it:

```
string="/home/rm/home-scripts/originals/audicerttest/incoming/TEST040511.txt"
parsed=$(awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {print $6, $7}' <<< ${string})
```

---

In general, suppose you have a file called `input_file.txt`:

```
/home/rm/home-scripts/originals/audicerttest/incoming/TEST040511.txt
/home/rm/home-scripts/originals/audicerttest2/incoming/TEST040512.txt
/home/rm/home-scripts/originals/audicerttest3/incoming/TEST040513.txt
```

You can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {print $6, $7}' input_file.txt > parsed_vars.txt
```

And `parsed_vars.txt` will contain:

```
audicerttest/incoming
audicerttest2/incoming
audicerttest3/incoming
```

---

**Some explanations:**

- `parsed=$(...)` - spawn a subshell and save the output to `stdout` within that subshell to the variable `parsed`
- `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}` - invoke `awk` and set delimiter as `/` for both input and output.
- `{print $6, $7}'` - based on the format of your raw strings, you want to print the 6th (audicerttest) and the 7th (incoming) fields.
- `<<< ${string}` is the notation for using [herestring](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html)
- `input_file.txt > parsed_vars.txt` - read from specified input file, and redirect output to an output file.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pure bash solution, not using any overkill `awk` and not using any evil `eval` and not using any subshells:

You have this string:

```
string="/home/rm/home-scripts/originals/audicerttest/incoming/TEST040511.txt"
```

You want a string that contains the 5th and 6th fields (where separation is `/`) in a variable `parsed`. Let's go:

```
IFS=/ a=( $string ) printf -v parsed '%s/%s' "${a[@]:5:2}"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo ${file} | eval $(awk '{split($0,a,"/"); print "abc=a[6]/a[7]"}' < /dev/null)
```

Okay, a couple of problems here.

`awk` is reading from `/dev/null`, which doesn't make any sense, guess you want to process the filename:

```
echo {$file} | awk ...
```

`"a[6]"` is the string `a[6]`, no substitution is made.

Now eval the whole thing:

```
eval $(echo $file | awk '{split($0,a,"/"); print "abc="a[6]"/"a[7]""}')
```

Finally, eval is evil, why don't you directly set the variable?

```
abc=$(echo $file | awk '{split($0,a,"/"); print a[6]"/"a[7]}')
```

On a personal note, I thing this is a bit more clear:

```
 cut -d / --output-delimiter / -f6,7
```

Comment: The main problem in your method is the useless use of `eval`. `eval` is evil! Not mentioning the useless uses of subshells.

Comment: I was just updating my answer... He is using an inefficient tool for the task, but (I hope) he's asking about *why* it didn't work, an not just asking for an other solution. So, no idea why the downvote.

Comment: I'm a total newbie to Shell. I agree there are too many mistakes. Thanks for correcting those.

Answer (score 1):

With only bash arrays, you could do the following:

Assuming:

```
path=/home/rm/home-scripts/originals/audicerttest/incoming/TEST040511.txt
```

Then:

```
IFS=/ split=(${path})
path_part="${split[5]}/${split[6]}"
```

`$split` will be an array, with element 0 empty, element one `home`, element 2 `rm`, etc. With that you just need to concatenate the elements you want to get the part you like.

Answer (score 0):

Nobody has suggested simple [parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to manipulate the strings. I'm assuming that the first 4 directories are constant

```
while read path; do
    dirname=$(dirname $path)
    abc=${dirname#/home/rm/home-scripts/originals/}
    echo "abc===$abc"
done < filename
```