# Save variable from txt using awk

Tags: bash, variables, awk

I have a txt in my folder named parameters.txt which contains

PP1 20 30 40 60

PP2 0 0 0 0

I'd like to use awk to read the different parameters depending on the value of the first text field in each line. At the moment, if I run

```
src_dir='/PP1/'
awk "$src_dir" '{ print $2 }' parameters.txt
```

I correctly get

```
20
```

I would simply like to store that 20 into a variable and to export the variable itself.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might want to take a look at the top answer for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634155/assign-a-shell-variable-in-awk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to save the output, do `var=$(awk expression)`:

```
result=$(awk -v value=$src_dir '($1==value) { print $2 }' parameters.txt)
```

You can make your command more general giving awk the variable with the `-v` syntax:

```
$ var="PP1"
$ awk -v v=$var '($1==v) { print $2 }' a
20
$ var="PP2"
$ awk -v v=$var '($1==v) { print $2 }' a
0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! I've tried the former command, but I get

Cannot open `{ print $2 }'

Comment: Ok! See my updated answer, I did not check your expression. Now I've done it.

Comment: Getting closer but still not there yet :)
I get no errors, but an echo $result gives a blank outcome!

Comment: Then let's work a little bit more on it! Do you previously set the variable with `src_dir="PP1"`? Otherwise, does this work to you? --> `result=$(awk -v value="PP1" '($1==value) { print $2 }' parameters.txt)`?

Comment: This way it does work indeed! What's the matter then?

src_dir was previously set with
$ src_dir=$i

i being a a vaiable cycling through different folder names..

Comment: I should see the full code to guess what can be wrong. Which of two parts I posted helped you?

Comment: for i in `ls -d */
do
 cd  $i
 src_dir=$i

 cd ..

 # result=$(awk -v value=$/src_dir '($1==value) { print $2 }'   parameters.txt)
 result=$(awk -v value="PP1" '($1==value) { print $2 }' parameters.txt)
 
 echo $result

done`

Here it is. The latter 'result=...' does allow the echo to print result, while the former one (here commented) does not. I must be missing something very stupid.

Comment: Just change `value=$/src_dir` to `value=$src_dir`. Should be this :)

Comment: Ahh! Here's the thing, maybe:
`echo $src_dir` performed after its first initialization (`src_dir=$i`) gives as output `/PP1/` rather than `PP1`. Is there a way to take out those two slashes automatically?

Thanks so much for your help!! Really appreciate

Comment: You shouldn't need the `/` expression. The way I posted it should be enough for the string comparison.

Comment: Exactly, I needed to take the slash out. I've used a workaround though, and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You don't really need `awk` for that. You can do it in `bash`.

```
$ src_dir="PP1"
$ while read -r pattern columns ; do 
      set - $columns
      if [[ $pattern  =~ $src_dir ]]; then 
          variable=$2
      fi
   done < parameters.txt
```

Comment: You can leave feedback in the comments instead of updating the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
shell_pattern=PP1
output_var=$(awk -v patt=$shell_pattern '$0 ~ patt {print $2}' file)
```

Note that `$output_var` may contain more than one value if the pattern matches more than one line. If you're only interested in the first value, then have the awk program `exit` after printing .

Comment: What would be the output variable?